# How to read XPathNodelist

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, ienumerable

Programming in C# I got an Xml.XpathNodeList object "ResultsPartRel.nodeList". Debugging it with Visual Studio I can read "Results View ; Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable"

**Questions:**

1.- Which is the best way to read those nodes?

2.- I program the next code but I dont get the expected results. I get the same result twice. (ResultsPartRel.nodeList contains 2 nodes)

```
         List<string> childrenName = new List<string>();

         foreach (XmlElement node in ResultsPartRel.nodeList)
         {
             string nameChildren = node.SelectSingleNode("//related_id/Item/keyed_name").InnerText;
             childrenName.Add(nameChildren);
         }
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
<related_id>
  <Item>
    <classification>Component</classification>
    <id></id>
    <keyed_name>glass</keyed_name> <!-- I want to get this InnerText -->
    </Item>
</related_id>
<source_id>968C45A47942454DA9B34245A9F72A8C</source_id>
<itemtype>5E9C5A12CC58413A8670CF4003C57848</itemtype>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we really need to see the XML sample and a verbal explanation of which data you want to extract. Currently you do a `node.SelectSingleNode(...)` so that looks as if you want to select a path relative to `node` but then you use an absolute path starting with `//`, that is why you get the same result twice.

So you want `node.SelectSingleNode(".//related_id/Item/keyed_name")` or perhaps even `node.SelectSingleNode("related_id/Item/keyed_name")`, depending on the XML you have.

Comment: When  `node.SelectSingleNode("related_id/Item/keyed_name")`I dont get any result. Thats why `node.SelectSingleNode("//related_id/Item/keyed_name")` I edit my question with XMLNode

Comment: Please also show where and how you initialize `ResultsPartRel.nodeList` so that we know the context node you call `SelectSingleNode` on.

Comment: `ResultsPartRel` is an object from a factory-class which is in XML based. `Item ResultsPartRel = ResultsPartObj.getRelationships();` I dont know what else I can show in order to clarify my problem.

Comment: We need to understand the relationship between the nodes you have in `ResultsPartRel.nodeList` and the sample XML you have posted. So post more context of the sample XML or at least post `node.OuterXml` so that we know how a `node` you are calling `SelectSingleNode` on looks like.

Comment: Foreach works fine. In every iteration the node from node list are different. The point is that ´SelectSingleNode´ does not work properly. It always shows the value from the first node.

Comment: @kmxillo: Why just not do what Martin advised: use `".//related_id/Item/keyed_name"`  Do note the starting dot in the expression -- this is the key in the solution.

Comment: Guys Works. for my understanding is a little bit complicated. I will research on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element. (With the "//" means search for all following tags, so you will probably get more results).When you want the first element write "//related_id/Item/keyed_name**[1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/)**".

Or you can write the exact path.(this is the safest way) To make it easy for yourself there is a Firefox extension [xPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) load the document in firefox than right click the element and show Xpath. Then you get a exact path.

Comment: My problems is that I just get  the first element in the foreach. The namechildren is duplicated.